# Remove commas between patterns

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to replace all commas with a space between ";" and "[" in my text file using `sed`. An example line is: `K01810,GPI,,pgi;,glucose-6-phosphate,isomerase,[EC:5.3.1.9]` where my ideal output is `K01810,GPI,,pgi; glucose-6-phosphate isomerase [EC:5.3.1.9]`.

I have tried `sed 's/;\(.*\)\[/;\1[/g' myfile.txt > newfile` but that didn't change anything.

myfile.txt:

```
09100,Metabolism
09101,Carbohydrate,metabolism
00010,Glycolysis,/,Gluconeogenesis,[PATH:ko00010]
K00844,HK;,hexokinase,[EC:2.7.1.1]
K12407,GCK;,glucokinase,[EC:2.7.1.2]
K00845,glk;,glucokinase,[EC:2.7.1.2]
K25026,glk;,glucokinase,[EC:2.7.1.2]
K01810,GPI,,pgi;,glucose-6-phosphate,isomerase,[EC:5.3.1.9]
K06859,pgi1;,glucose-6-phosphate,isomerase,,archaeal,[EC:5.3.1.9]
K13810,tal-pgi;,transaldolase,/,glucose-6-phosphate,isomerase,[EC:2.2.1.2,5.3.1.9]
K15916,pgi-pmi;,glucose/mannose-6-phosphate,isomerase,[EC:5.3.1.9,5.3.1.8]
K24182,PFK9;,6-phosphofructokinase,[EC:2.7.1.11]
K00850,pfkA,,PFK;,6-phosphofructokinase,1,[EC:2.7.1.11]
K16370,pfkB;,6-phosphofructokinase,2,[EC:2.7.1.11]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '
    # skip lines that do not match
    /^\(.*\)\(;.*\[\)\(.*\)$/ ! b

    # save a copy of original line
    h

    # extract prefix/suffix
    s//\1\n\3/

    # save them, restore original line
    x

    # extract part to change
    s//\2/

    # do the substitution
    y/,/ /

    # append prefix/suffix
    G

    # rearrange
    s/^\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)\n/\2\1/
    
' myfile.txt >newfile
```

---

**Note:** For portability, escaped literal newline is required in replacement (some versions of sed treat `\n` as just `n`):

```
    # ...

    # extract prefix/suffix
    s//\1\
\3/

    # ...
```

Comment: Wow, I am so grateful for your explanation!  Thank you kind stranger.

Comment: Perl is a bit shorter: `perl -ple 's:;.*\[:y/,/ /r:e' myfile.txt >newfile`

Comment: Thank you.  I realize now I have some lines that don't contain a "[" but I still need all commas removed after the ";".

Comment: the first three lnes of input in your question don't contain `;`. you can probably adjust my regex to split your lines into prefix / part to change / suffix using whatever rules you need. I can only guess what those rules should be

Comment: oops. wrong variable: `perl -pe 's:;.*\[:$&=~y/,/ /r:e' ...`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/(;[^,[]*),/\1 /;ta' file
```

Match any succession of characters starting with a `;` and not containing either `[` or `,`, followed by a `,` and replace the `,` with a space.

If the substitution is successful, repeat until failure.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's{(;[^;\[]+)}{ do { $s = $1; $s =~ tr/,/ /; $s } }e; ' infile > outfile
```

or change it in-place:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's{(;[^;\[]+)}{ do { $s = $1; $s =~ tr/,/ /; $s } }e; ' infile
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

The regex uses this modifier:
`/e` : Evaluate `REPLACEMENT` as an expression in `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/`

`s{PATTERN}{EXPRESSION}` : replace `PATTERN` with `EXPRESSION`.
`(;[^;\[]+)` : literal `;`, followed by 1 or more of any character except `;` or `[` (note that is has to be escaped: `\[`. The parentheses capture the match into variable `$1`.
`do { $s = $1; $s =~ tr/,/ /; $s }` : reassign `$1` to `$s`, then change all occurrences of `,` to   (space). The block returns the last expression, which is the variable `$s` after these changes.

**See also:**

- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
- [`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
- [`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*;)([^[]+)(\[.*)/,a) {
    $0 = a[1] gensub(/,/," ","g",a[2]) a[3]
} 1' file
09100,Metabolism
09101,Carbohydrate,metabolism
00010,Glycolysis,/,Gluconeogenesis,[PATH:ko00010]
K00844,HK; hexokinase [EC:2.7.1.1]
K12407,GCK; glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.2]
K00845,glk; glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.2]
K25026,glk; glucokinase [EC:2.7.1.2]
K01810,GPI,,pgi; glucose-6-phosphate isomerase [EC:5.3.1.9]
K06859,pgi1; glucose-6-phosphate isomerase  archaeal [EC:5.3.1.9]
K13810,tal-pgi; transaldolase / glucose-6-phosphate isomerase [EC:2.2.1.2,5.3.1.9]
K15916,pgi-pmi; glucose/mannose-6-phosphate isomerase [EC:5.3.1.9,5.3.1.8]
K24182,PFK9; 6-phosphofructokinase [EC:2.7.1.11]
K00850,pfkA,,PFK; 6-phosphofructokinase 1 [EC:2.7.1.11]
K16370,pfkB; 6-phosphofructokinase 2 [EC:2.7.1.11]
```

or you can do the same using any awk with:

```
awk 'match($0,/(.*;)([^[]+)(\[.*)/) {
    tgt = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); gsub(/,/," ",tgt)
    $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) tgt substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
} 1' file
```